# How to stop Viber running without uninstalling it?

Tags: services, viber-messenger

How do I stop Viber running, without uninstalling the app? When I go Menu→More options→Exit it just comes back. I want it to turn it off completely, so it's not waiting to come on in the background.

Comment: Viber is just bloatware that forces you to use it, you cannot close it, only option is to uninstall.

Comment: Oh this is so annoying. I can exit from Skype, from fb messenger, from hangout, from lync. But not from this. Only hard stop of apps helps. Via settings-apps-running

Answer (score 4):

This is an official rep. of Viber.

Due to the C2DM feature, you are always available on Viber, there is not way to  "log out" and "log in".
Please note that if you "exit" Viber, it will open again only if you get a msg or call.

Let us know if you have any additional questions.

Thanks!
Viber Team

Comment: Funny!God bless telegram.

Comment: Hi @Viber , Can you create an option to disable auto start? It's pointless (and waste battery) to run Viber when there isn't internet. (also I want to use Viber to call others rather than let others call me)

Answer (score 4):

No need to root or anything. You can just simply stop it being running by going to **Settings>application>viber>force close** this will close all the services related to viber. But remind you, you have to force close it every time after you use viber.

Oh there is another way to do that. Start viber, then close it. Then open your multitasking window/history window by pressing the home button. you should see viber there at the bottom. Long press on the screen-shot of viber. You should be prompted with two option, **app details/info and clear from list** tap on **app details/info** and click on **force close** this will do your job.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just wanted to add that after phone reboot Viber will be running again. So, if you, for example, want to avoid network access by Viber for some reason, then close all network connections before reboot, reboot, disable Viber service and then enable network connections again.

Answer (score 3):

There is an app for this if you have root: [Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify)

Comment: But that'll require root which will void warranty.

Comment: Not really. Well if you are in the EU it doesn't, see this link: http://matija.suklje.name/rooting-and-flashing-your-device-does-not-void-the-warranty-in-eu

Comment: This is the way I do it too, but sometimes it still starts up.

Answer (score 1):

I have Viber on phone and tablet and it behaves differently. By default, no matter how you stop the service it always turns on when you receive message.

On phone when I go to settings - general - turn off "show Viber status icon", and then I just exit the Viber (via exit or stop service or clean task manager) I am really offline. All messages are received after I turn on Viber myself. I can be offline for days. It behaves like this only when I turn off the Viber icon.

I guess this is a bug but I like it and hope it is not going to be fixed. I don't know if it is bug just for combination of my phone and Android version or if it "works" like this on every phone. On tablet this does not work, Viber cannot be really off.

Answer (score 0):

Battery saver is the easy option without any additional apps.

Many Mobile manufacturing companies give some inbuilt apps to control background running apps, check if you have one.

If it's a basic stock Android then you need to install 3rd party apps like Greenify or something else..

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK you can't stop the process in the background without unistalling it. You can logout from your viber account, then it won't display you any notifications

// I must add to here, that once you logged in Viber has no known way to log out