# How can I disable viber on my stolen device?

Tags: viber-messenger

My mobile phone has been stolen. How can i stop viber services process?

I need your urgent help to stop the people reach my friends.

Comment: You should not expose personal information in your posts. I doubt that it's possible, but I am not a viber user and could be wrong. IMHO the best you can do is ask to second party to inform your contacts that your phone has been compromised.

Answer (score 1):

Viber is linked to you phone number, not to the Device? Why don't you block your SIM-card (this will not deactivate your Viber), get a new card from your cell operator, then install and activate viber on it, then deactivate youe account?

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop the Viber process. Only way to stop Viber is by uninstalling.

See this: [How to stop Viber running without uninstalling it?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54977/how-to-stop-viber-running-without-uninstalling-it/)

> Due to the C2DM feature, you are always available on
>   Viber, there is not way to "log out" and "log in". Please
>   note that if you "exit" Viber, it will open again only if
>   you get a msg or call.
>   Let us know if you have any additional questions.
>   Thanks! Viber Team

Answer (score 0):

First you can login to another device with same ID. After that you should de-activate your viber account. Then reactivate your account in new device with same ID(phone number) with different password.

**Steps:**

1. Open Viber
2. Enter the More Options menu
3. Select Settings
4. Select Privacy
5. Select Deactivate Account

Deactivation can only take place within the application.

What happens when I deactivate my account?
Deactivating your account will erase everything associated with your Viber ID, including your call and message history, groups and downloaded stickers (both free and purchased). It will also unlink all other accounts linked to your Viber account (e.g. Twitter, Facebook).

Once an account is deactivated, there is no way to restore any of its information. Re-registering to Viber with the same Viber ID (phone number) will not restore the previous account history.

Viber Out credits will not be lost if your account is deactivated.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot disable it remotely.

Maximum that you can do you can delete your messages from other device.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivating your viber account with the same phone number is not possible because viber will send the code to your stolen sim so there is no way you can reactivate it to another device then deactivate.

Answer (score -2):

My device has been lost or stolen. What happens to my Viber account?
You may re-install Viber on your new device using the old device’s phone number. This will reinstate the previous account on your new device.